# correlation matrix MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix

Do you know a matlab script that gets the correlation matrix of a set of data like numbe of columns=7, and rows = n>>7

```
 x1      x2      x3      x4     x5     x6      x7 

0.780   2.042   2.754   2.894  5.000  5.000  5.000
0.767   0.816   2.758   2.898  5.000  1.644  1.626
0.816   0.836   1.558   2.124  2.952  5.000  5.000
0.848   0.871   1.588   2.147  2.966  5.000  5.000
1.378   1.620   1.433   2.567  3.268  3.203  5.000
....
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try [`corrcoef`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/corrcoef.html).

In general, you can find these sort of things immediately by searching the online help, for example via the convenient `lookfor` command:

```
>> lookfor correlation
corrcoef                       - Correlation coefficients.
msfuncorr                      - an M-S-function which performs auto- and cross-
...

>> help corrcoef
CORRCOEF Correlation coefficients.
   R=CORRCOEF(X) calculates a matrix R of correlation coefficients for
   an array X, in which each row is an observation and each column is a
   variable.
```

For instance

```
load file.txt
result= CORRCOEF(file);
```