# Matlab: How to generate a 4x1 matrix of random variables, assuming a 4x4 correlation matrix?

Tags: matlab, statistics, probability, correlation, montecarlo

I start with 4 time series, labelled A, B, C, D.

I generate the following:

- A 4x1 matrix of means.
- A 4x1 matrix of standard deviations.
- A 4x4 [correlation matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5054475/correlation-matrix-matlab), by taking 30 samples from each time series.

What is the Matlab code to generate a 4x1 matrix of random variables, keeping the correlations between the time series intact?

(reason: this is the first stage in a Monte Carlo simulation).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need just the means vector (call it `m`) and the covariance matrix (call it `C`). Note that you can get the covariance matrix from the correlation using the equation `C = R - m*m'` (or just compute it directly by computing the correlation of the sequences after subtracting their mean).

Then, to get a vector with the covariance C, you generate an IID random vector (say gaussian):

```
w = randn(4,1)
```

Then multiply it with the *square root* of the covariance matrix (call it Q) and add the mean:

```
v = Q*w + m
```

You can either use Matlab's sqrt function to compute sqrt(C) or compute it using the SVD or EIG.

```
[u,d] = eig(C)

Q = u*sqrt(d)*u'
```

The covariance of `v` will be `Q*Q'` (=`C`) and the mean will be `m`

See the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_matrix#Properties) for the properties of the covariance matrix.

Comment: just to add.. another way to get `Q` would be Cholesky decomposition using `chol`. But `C` needs to be positive definite for this. If it's only positive semi-definite, SVD is probably the only way.

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to the Statistics toolbox, you can use `mvnrnd` to generate the numbers.

First calculate the covariance matrix, `C`, using `cov` or the method described in nimrodm's answer.  Then simply call

```
mvnrnd(m, C)
```

where `m` is your vector of means.